# Custom type in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a document in ElasticSearch:

```
"_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.test.request.DocsFindRequest",
          "registerNumber" : "string",
          "sender" : {
            "first" : "string",
            "person" : {
              "first" : "string",
              "name" : "string"
            },
            "senderType" : "string",
            "originId" : "string",
            "members" : [
              {
                "second" : "string",
                "firstName" : "string",
                "middleName" : "string",
                "lastName" : "string",
                "main" : true
              }
            ]
          },
          "representer" : {
            "first" : "string",
            "second" : "string"
          },
          "summary" : "string",
          "category" : "incoming",
          "music" : "string"
        }
```

And I`m trying to compare all fields in Elastic with my fields in Java with painless.
So, fields like `registerNumber` works fine, and script `if (params._source.registerNumber == params.registerNumber) ...` works fine too. But, with array I have problem like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot write xcontent for unknown value of type class com.test.request.Members
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.unknownValue(XContentBuilder.java:833) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.map(XContentBuilder.java:895) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.map(XContentBuilder.java:870) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:866) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.script.Script.toXContent(Script.java:660) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:857) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.value(XContentBuilder.java:850) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.field(XContentBuilder.java:842) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder$ScriptField.toXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:1530) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.innerToXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:1275) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.toXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:1355) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.toXContent(XContentHelper.java:367) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.createEntity(RequestConverters.java:768) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.createEntity(RequestConverters.java:763) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.search(RequestConverters.java:417) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$search$2(RestHighLevelClient.java:1071) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1609) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1583) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1553) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:1069) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
    at az.cybernet.vis.elastic.ElasticIndexer.getFromIndex(ElasticIndexer.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at az.cybernet.vis.kafka.KafkaConsumer.consume(KafkaConsumer.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:330) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2069) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2051) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1988) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to close the XContentBuilder
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.close(XContentBuilder.java:1011) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.toXContent(XContentHelper.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unclosed object or array found
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator.close(JsonXContentGenerator.java:469)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.close(XContentBuilder.java:1009)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

It`s happening when I`m create the Script with params, like so:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("members", request.getSender().getMembers());



Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", scrip, params);
```

I`m don`t understand, what I`m doing wrong.

Please help.

Comment: did u solve it?